# remotely play ringtone on android/IOS phone

Tags: android, ios, find, viber

Several years ago i developed android app that created alarm clock at certain time when some notification was received. Android programming is complicated they keep changing things make it more difficult for apps to run in background ect.

So for sending notifications i use viber bot which works fine for messages. The problem is that sometimes i want to send an alert (ringtone/music) that last at least 30 seconds since I am sleeping at that time and might not hear simple notification. I know i could change ringtone for viber, but i would like to use it for different purposes with normal notifications. What would work is to set custom ringtone only for certain viber bot but from my understanding this doesn't work. Making a voice call would work but from my understanding this is not possible from command line at least not for free.

I found googles function "locate my phone" that start a ringtone but i didnt find if i can do it outside of web browser. So basically i am searching for a way how i can send command from my linux server that would start ringing on my phone and other people's phone that give me permission.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I manage to solve this by using using Telegram android app and python script https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram to make a call.